# Refactoring the if statement for the dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, foreach, refactoring

***I was asked to refactor the following:***

```
 if (
                      cell.column.id === 'maintenance_from' ||
                      cell.column.id === 'reg_number_CPDP_date' ||
                      cell.column.id === 'license_date_of_issue'
                    ) {
                      let timestamp = '';
                      Object.keys(cell?.row?.original).forEach(
                        (item: any) => {
                          if (
                            item === 'maintenance_from' ||
                            item === 'reg_number_CPDP_date' ||
                            item === 'license_date_of_issue'
                          ) {
                            timestamp = cell?.row?.original[item];
                          }
                        }
                      );
                      return (
                        <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                          {DateParse(timestamp)}
                        </td>
                      );
```

***from the following code:***

```
    import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ExtendedTableColumnProps } from 'shared/types/table';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Box, Button, Checkbox, Grid, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import Loader from 'shared/components/Loader/Loader';
import useTranslationRedux from 'shared/hooks/useTranslation';
import { useAsyncFn, useMount } from 'react-use';
import I18nService from 'shared/services/I18nService';
import { PORTAL_BASE_ROUTE } from '../../../shared/navigation/portalRoutes';
import DateParse from '../../../shared/utils/parseDate';

interface TableProps {
  loading?: boolean;
  classes: any;
  instance: any;
  formProps: any;
  setLinkedObjectId?: any;
  type: any;
  selectedLayer: any;
  setFeatureId?: any;
}

const LinkedObjectsFormRowTable: React.FC<TableProps> = ({
  classes,
  instance,
  formProps,
  setLinkedObjectId,
  type,
  loading,
  selectedLayer,
  setFeatureId,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [checkboxesState, setCheckboxesState] = useState<any>({});

  const { language } = useTranslationRedux();

  const arrOfNonSpatialData = [
    'logical_networks',
    'buildings',
    'dam_usages',
    'legal_entities',
    'licenses',
    'maintenances',
    'municipalities',
    'water_volumes',
    'water_pump_station_pumps',
    'sewer_pump_station_pumps',
    'irrigate_system_drainage_data',
    'wwtp_data_per_year',
    'water_supply_systems',
    'wastewater_disposal_and_treatment_systems',
    'sewer_networks',
    // 'measurement_devices',
  ];

  const [featuresTranslationsResponse, loadTranslations] = useAsyncFn(
    (layerName: string) => I18nService.layersTransations.getSingle(layerName),
    []
  );

  useMount(() => {
    if (formProps.initialValues.linkedObjectId) {
      setCheckboxesState({
        [formProps.initialValues.linkedObjectId]: true,
      });
    }
  });

  const reloadTranslatons = () => {
    const nonSpatialView = 'view_';

    if (arrOfNonSpatialData.includes(selectedLayer)) {
      loadTranslations(nonSpatialView.concat(selectedLayer));
    } else {
      loadTranslations(selectedLayer);
    }
  };

  useEffect(reloadTranslatons, [language]);

  const featuresTranslations: any =
    featuresTranslationsResponse.value?.data ?? [];

  const translateHeader = useCallback(
    (element: string) => {
      const translation = featuresTranslations?.columns?.find(
        (c: any) => c?.columnKey === element
      );
      return translation?.value.length > 0 ? translation?.value : t(element);
    },
    [featuresTranslations, t]
  );

  const handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    isNonSpacial: boolean,
    row: any
  ) => {
    const checkBoxVal = Number(e.target.name);

    if (isNonSpacial) {
      Object.keys(row.original).forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.startsWith('pk') && item.endsWith('id')) {
          if (setLinkedObjectId) {
            setLinkedObjectId(row.original[item]);
          }
          formProps.setFieldValue('linkedObjectId', row.original[item]);
          setCheckboxesState({
            [row.original[item]]: e.target.checked,
          });
        } else if (item.includes('featureId') && setFeatureId) {
          setFeatureId(row.original[item].split('.')[0]);
        }
      });
    } else {
      setCheckboxesState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.checked,
      });
      if (e.target.checked) {
        formProps.setFieldValue('linkedObjectId', checkBoxVal);
        if (setLinkedObjectId) {
          setLinkedObjectId(checkBoxVal);
        }
      } else {
        formProps.setFieldValue('linkedObjectId', '');
        if (setLinkedObjectId) {
          setLinkedObjectId('');
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    rows,
  } = instance;

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader text={t('pleaseWait')} isLoading size={100} />
      ) : (
        <Box
          className={classes.featuresTableContainer2}
          style={{ padding: 0 }}
          mt={2}
        >
          <Box className="tableScrollContainer" style={{ maxHeight: '200px' }}>
            <table
              {...getTableProps()}
              cellSpacing={0}
              className={classes.table}
            >
              <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((group: any) => (
                  <tr {...group.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {(group.headers as ExtendedTableColumnProps[]).map(
                      column => {
                        return (
                          <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                            <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                              {translateHeader(column.id)}
                            </Box>
                          </th>
                        );
                      }
                    )}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </thead>
              <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row: any) => {
                  prepareRow(row);
                  return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                      {row.cells.map((cell: any) => {
                        if (/*fkNetworkElId &&*/ cell.column.id === 'choose') {
                          const nameKey: string =
                            Object.keys(cell.row.original).find(
                              key => key.startsWith('pk') && key.endsWith('id')
                            ) || '';
                          const nameValue =
                            type !== 'nonSpatialObjects'
                              ? cell.row.original.fk_network_element_id
                              : cell.row.original[nameKey];
                          return (
                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              <Checkbox
                                value={nameValue}
                                checked={checkboxesState[nameValue] || false}
                                onChange={e =>
                                  handleChange(
                                    e,
                                    type === 'nonSpatialObjects',
                                    cell.row
                                  )
                                }
                                name={nameValue}
                              />
                            </td>
                          );
                        }

                        if (
                          cell.column.id === 'options' &&
                          type !== 'nonSpatialObjects'
                        ) {
                          return (
                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              <Tooltip title={`${t('linkedObjectsInfo')}`}>
                                <span>
                                  <Button
                                    className={classes.button}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      const layerName = cell.row.original.featureId.split(
                                        '.'
                                      );
                                      const url = `${PORTAL_BASE_ROUTE}/linked-objects/${cell.row.original.fk_network_element_id}/${layerName[0]}`;
                                      window.open(url, '_blank');
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <i
                                      className={
                                        'fas fa-external-link-alt fa-lg'
                                      }
                                      style={{ margin: '3px 0 0 2px' }}
                                    />
                                  </Button>
                                </span>
                              </Tooltip>
                              <Tooltip title={`${t('showOnMap')}`}>
                                <span>
                                  <Button
                                    className={classes.button}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      const layerName = cell.row.original.featureId.split(
                                        '.'
                                      );
                                      const url = `${PORTAL_BASE_ROUTE}?layer=${layerName[0]}&id=${cell.row.original.fk_network_element_id}`;
                                      window.open(url, '_blank');
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <i
                                      className={'fas fa-map-marked-alt fa-lg'}
                                      style={{ margin: '3px 0 0 2px' }}
                                    />
                                  </Button>
                                </span>
                              </Tooltip>
                            </td>
                          );
                        }

                        if (
                          cell.column.id === 'maintenance_from' ||
                          cell.column.id === 'reg_number_CPDP_date' ||
                          cell.column.id === 'license_date_of_issue'
                        ) {
                          let timestamp = '';
                          Object.keys(cell?.row?.original).forEach(
                            (item: any) => {
                              if (
                                item === 'maintenance_from' ||
                                item === 'reg_number_CPDP_date' ||
                                item === 'license_date_of_issue'
                              ) {
                                timestamp = cell?.row?.original[item];
                              }
                            }
                          );
                          return (
                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              {DateParse(timestamp)}
                            </td>
                          );
                        } else {
                          return (
                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              {cell.render('Cell')}
                            </td>
                          );
                        }
                      })}
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default LinkedObjectsFormRowTable;
```

So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?
So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?
So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?
So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?
So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?
So many question is, how could I please make it this fragment smaller, better?

Comment: First of all you sure did post a lot of code that noone needs to answer the question. secondly you should include code that YOU did write on HOW you tried to solve the question at hand. Everyone here helps others, but nobody here wants to do your work for you.
see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multiple if..else with array.includes method.

```
const STACK1 = ['maintenance_from', 'reg_number_CPDP_date', 'license_date_of_issue'];
if (STACK1.includes(cell.column.id)) {
    let timestamp = '';
    Object.keys(cell?.row?.original).forEach(
        (item: any) => {
            const STACK2 = ['maintenance_from', 'reg_number_CPDP_date', 'license_date_of_issue']
            if (STACK2.includes(item)) {
                timestamp = cell?.row?.original[item];
            }
        });
```